# Get State from mobx store react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mobx, mobx-react

I am just learning React JS. I want to get a value that is stored in mobx state in my application. But not getting any idea how to get mobx state in functional component.

```
const user_id = observer(({ GlobalStore }) =>
    console.log(GlobalStore.user_id)
); // I just need the user ID.
```

This is the full code:

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
import Store from "../mobx/Store";

export const user_id = observer(({ GlobalStore }) =>
    console.log(GlobalStore)
);

console.log(user_id);
```

And my Store.js file is as below:

```html
import { observable, action, makeObservable, autorun } from "mobx";
class GlobalStore {
    site_title = "ABCD";
    app_code = null;
    user_id = null;

    constructor() {
        makeObservable(this, {
            site_title: observable,
            app_code: observable,
            user_id: observable,
            update_title: action.bound,
            update_appcode: action.bound,
            update_userid: action.bound,
        });
    }

    update_title(title) {
        this.site_title = title;
    }
    update_appcode(code) {
        this.app_code = code;
    }
    update_userid(id) {
        this.user_id = id;
    }
}

const Store = new GlobalStore();
autorun(() => {
    console.log("System Checking... OK")
})
export default Store;
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want exactly? Do you just want to render some value from your Store in React component? It is unclear because you don't have a Component in your example, `user_id` is just a function that logs things, it does not have any jsx even.

Comment: @Danila I just want to get mobx state (user_id) as `user_id = Get mobx state here anyhow` in a different functional component or module

Answer (score 1):

in Mobx Update Version We have autoObservable

import makeAutoObservable from Mobx and use it like i have used check out code sandbox

-> here You can Check

code for Your mobx Store

```
import { makeAutoObservable, runInAction } from 'mobx'; // import this
    
    class GlobalStore {
      user_id = 'id here';
    
      constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this); // call autuobservable inside constractor
      }
    
      update_userid(id) {
        this.user_id = id;
      }
    }
    
    const Store = new GlobalStore();
    
    export default Store;
```

and here you can access your user id like this in app component or where else you want

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Store from './Store';
import './styles.css';
    const App = observer(() => {
      useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          Store.update_userid('new_id_111');
        }, 3000);
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
          <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
          <div>user_id: {Store.user_id}</div>
        </div>
      );
    });
    export default App;
```

reference code sandbox link

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-68329454-forked-roniod?file=/src/Store.js:159-184)

it may solve your problem

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33116198)

Comment: @MeetBhalodiya tnx for your notice, i have update the answer

Answer (score -1):

Because your store is a singleton you can just import it anywhere and access any field or method.

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

import Store from './Store';

const SomeComponent = observer(() => {
  return <div>user_id: {Store.user_id}</div>;
});
```

I've made [example on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions68329454-2illu)